# how to map a joined ResultSet to an object in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I took the example from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372152/Mapping-JDBC-ResultSet-to) to map `ResultSet` to an `Object` , and it works great, but then I just realized a problem that I can't map `ResultSet` from a join query. for example I have two tables, `usr` and `vehicle`. I do a `select` query and join those two.

```
public class Usr {
    public int id;
    public Vehicle vehicle;
}

public class Vehicle {
    public int id;
    public int year;
    public String model;
    public int user_id;
}
```

how can I map `ResultSet` to the `Usr` object? I googled a bit and found `SqlResultSetMapping` might be a solution, but it seems like a lot of work to adopt Hibernate, and I'm only familiar with pure `Java`. from the example [here](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-complex-mappings/), looks like I would need to rewrite all my query statements and put my db structure in `Java`.

Is there any other ways that I can just map the joined `ResultSet` to an object without too much mess on the current code?

**EDITED**

the query is something like this;

```
select * from usr join vehicle on usr.id = vehicle.user_id;
```

and I want to map it back to the `Usr` object

Comment: Yes its possible but you did not say what exactly the **join query** you are using and how do you want to map the **ResultSet**  to which class ?

Comment: The example explains a simple hand rolled mapping, which is hardly useful. It's half way between using straight JDBC and using Hibernate. If you want to handle lots of complicated mappings, you can learn Hibernate. If you wish to handle things manually, do it normally without the help of that example. Or even better, find a framework that only does the mapping and use that.

Comment: Can you provide me the query you are using for retrieving `Usr` from the resultset ? Is it just like `select * from usr` and your exsiting code can do the mapping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break the whole thing in a new way. The approach you are following is handy but comes with limitations. It only handles the primitive types of field. But what about the classes having association with other Objects or tables in db as foreign key mapping ? Like the case you are having `Usr` class in which you have `Vehicle` as an associated relation.

Rather than doing the mapping in too much generic way, you could write the mapping logic in a class then reuse it when necessary.

Write an `RowMapper` abstract class

```
public abstract class RowMapper<E> {

    public List<E> processResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
         List<E> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

         while(rs.next()) {
            objectList.add(mapRow(rs));
         }

         return objectList;
    }

    abstract E mapRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
}
```

Now write the *Row Mapping* logic for the`Usr` class

```
public class UsrMapper extends RowMapper<Usr> {

    @Override
    public State mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        Usr usr = new Usr();
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();

        usr.setId(rs.getInt("usr.id"));
        vehicle.setId(rs.getInt("vehicle.id"));
        vehicle.setYear(rs.getInt("vehicle.year"));
        vehicle.setModel(rs.getString("vehicle.model"));

        usr.setVehicle(vehicle);

        return usr;
    }
}
```

You can have implement another **RowMapper** for `Vehicle` as well. Now its just a way to go using this.

Say you got your **ResultSet** from the following join query

```
select usr.id, vehicle.id, vehicle.year, vehicle.model from usr join vehicle on usr.id = vehicle.user_id;
```

Now

```
UsrMapper usrMapper = new UsrMapper();
List<Usr> usrList = usrMapper.processResultSet(resultSet);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I should've mentioned it in my question. what I really wanted is a generic mapper method that can handle all the mapping like in the example. is it possible to do that?

Comment: yes. that also possible. but I afraid that would not be this straight forward. you need have to check for different types of relation between entity and parse mapping logic from some kind of annotations. But for why do you re invent the wheel ? standard ORM frameworks are already there to do this job efficiently. If it only because you just want to stick with pure java then this **RowMapper** pattern could be more convinient way to go.

Comment: I guess I'll go with this then implement Hibernate when I have time. hopefully the project won't be too huge by then

Comment: Does it work `rs.getInt("vehicle.id")` without  `SELECT vehicle.id AS "vehicle.id"` ?Thank you for the answer =)

Comment: @Waka Waka No, it wont. Cause you need some way to find the exact column from resutset. You can do it by mentioning the `columnIndex` or `columnLabel`

Comment: This would not even work when joining to a table that results in multiple rows which is the question. You will end up with far more users that required due to row s partially repeating data.